# how i get the 2nd object of a Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

i have this code:

```
public class Game {
    String NO_MOVEMENTS = ChatColor.RED+"You don't have sufficient movements to do that";
    public static HashMap<Player,Integer> movements = new HashMap<>();
    public void setupMovements(Player player){
        movements.put(player,15);
    }
    public void movementsManager(Player player){
    }
    public static HashMap arrowShoow(Player player){
    }
}
```

And i need to know the "movements"(int) of the hashmap, how i do get it??
thank you so much!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to know which Player has a specific Integer value?

Comment: Are you looking for `movements.get(player)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If** you want to know the `Integer` value for a specified `Player`:

```
Integer value = movements.get(player);
```

**If** you want to know the `Player` for a specified `Integer`:

```
Integer value = 15; /* put the int value you are looking for here */
Player player = movements.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().equals(value));
```

Keep in mind that if there is no `Player` for a specific `Integer`, you will get a null.

**If** you want the second object inserted into the map, you will need to use a `LinkedHashMap`, which retains the order in which keys were inserted into the map. To retrieve the second item inserted into the map:

```
Player player = movements.keySet().get(1);
```

Note: this assumes that there are at least two items in the map. It can also change if you remove an item from the map (because if you remove the first item from the map, the second item will become the first).

Answer (score 2):

The **Order** (of entry) is not preserved in HashMap, unlike ArrayList. And there is no way you can get the so called `second`object in HashMap.

To access all the elements in a HashMap you can look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46908/1475228).

To get the movement of a particular player you can use:

```
Integer movement = movements.get(yourPlayerObject);
```

Comment: The order can change within the same JVM.

Comment: I have a suspicion OP means the second type parameter, in other words, how to get a value from a map.